# how to display the short description in my cart and the checkout

Tags: woocommerce, cart

I would like to display the short description of my product rather than its name in my cart and the checkout I went to the cart.php file and I found a code I think I must change it
someone would have a solution for me ?

```
    <td class="product-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
    <?php
    if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
    echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), 
    $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;' );
    } else {
    echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', 
    esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) );
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the short description in the cart and in the checkout you can do it using the `woocommerce_cart_item_name` hook.

**If you want to show the short description of all product** types you can use this code:

```
// returns the short description as the cart item name
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'change_cart_item_name', 99, 3 );
function change_cart_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key  ) {

    $product = $cart_item['data'];

    // get short description
    $short_description = $product->get_short_description();

    // if it exists, it returns the short description as the cart item name
    if ( ! empty( $short_description ) ) {
        return $short_description;
    } else {
        return $item_name;
    }

    return $item_name;

}
```

If, in the case of product variations, **you want to show the short description of the parent product (variable product)** you can use the following code:

```
// returns the short description as the cart item name
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'change_cart_item_name', 99, 3 );
function change_cart_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key  ) {

    $product = $cart_item['data'];

    // if it is a variation it gets the description of the variable product
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
        $parent_id = $product->get_parent_id();
        $variable = wc_get_product( $parent_id );
        $short_description = $variable->get_short_description();
    } else {
        // get short description
        $short_description = $product->get_short_description();
    }

    // if it exists, it returns the short description as the cart item name
    if ( ! empty( $short_description ) ) {
        return $short_description;
    } else {
        return $item_name;
    }

    return $item_name;

}
```

It works both on the cart page and in the checkout.

The code must be added in your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: SUPER MERCI CA MARCHE

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use a hook. for example:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'ywp_custom_text_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function ywp_custom_text_cart_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $item_name .= '<br /><div class="my-custom-text-class">Custom text comes here</div>';

    return $item_name;
}
```

Code goes in `functions.php` file of your active theme/child theme. Tested and works.